# Constructing Diffeomorphism with prescribed derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am in the following situation: I am working in $S^1\times\mathbb{R}^2$ and have two
different frames for $T(S^1\times\mathbb{R}^2)$, given by $X_1,X_2, X_3$ and
$Y_1, Y_2=\partial_x, Y_3=\partial_y$, both of which are defined only on $S^1$ ($\partial_\theta$ is a non-zero vector field which is a positive basis for $TS^1$). Furthermore all the vector fields are nowhere tangent to $S^1\times\{0\}$. I now want to find
a diffeomorphism $f$ from an open neighbourhood of $S^1\times\{0\}$ to an open
neighbourhood of $S^1\times\{0\}$ such that

- $f$ is given by the Identity on $S^1\times\{0\}$
- for any $p\in S^1\times\{0\}$ we have $T_p f(X_i) = Y_i$.

Does anyone know of a theorem which would guarantee the existence of $f$, so far I have only found Whiteney's Extension Theorem and the extension lemma (Lemma 2.26) in Lee's
*Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, both of which do not cover my case since there are restrictions on either the domain or range of $f$.

Comment: By "transverse" do you mean "nowhere tangent"? A vector field cannot be transverse to a submanifold of codimension $>1$.

Comment: What are the $Y_i$? Are they specified, too?

Comment: My point is that your question above is still ill-stated, since nothing is said about the $Y_i$ except that they should be the images of $T_pf$

Comment: You are right, something got lost during an edit, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

This is not always possible.  To see this, suppose $X_1$ is actually tangent to $S^1\times \{0\}$ and $Y_1 = -X_1$.  Then there cannot be an $f$ meeting your criteria.

The point is that since $f$ is the identity on $S^1\times \{0\}$, $T_pf$ must be the identity on $T_p(S^1\times \{0\}) \subseteq T_p (S^1\times \mathbb{R}^2)$ for any $p\in S^1\times \{0\}$.

I'm not sure what kind of conditions one should impose on how $\{X_i\}$ is related to $\{Y_i\}$ in order to guarantee such an $f$ exists.

Comment: Good point, I actually know a little bit more about the frames, I know that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are all transverse to $S^1\times\{0\}$ and $Y_1  = \partial_\theta, Y_2 = \partial_x, Y_3 = \partial_y$. I will change the question.

Comment: @Universal:  Since $Y_1$ is tangent to $S^2\times\{0\}$ and $X_1$ isn't, can't you apply my argument using $f^{-1}$ instead of $f$ in order to show $f$ doesn't exist in this case?

Comment: Good point, what if I assume that all of the vector fields are nowhere transverse to $S^1\times\{0\}$?

Comment: @UniversalProperty:  There are still issues, such as those given in Kajelad's second bullet point.

Answer (score 5):

This map won't generally exist; there are all kinds of obstructions to consider:

- Let $t(X)\subset S^1$ denote the set of points for which $X$ is tangent to $S^1\times\{0\}$. Since this property is preserved by any diffeomorphism $f$ which preserves $S^1\times\{0\}$, we must have $t(X_i)=t(Y_i)$.
- Every vector field on $S^1\times\{0\}$ nowhere tangent to $S^1\times\{0\}$ can be identified with a loop in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$, and thus an element of $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\})\cong \mathbb{Z}$, allowing us to compute the winding number $w(X)\in\mathbb{Z}$ of any such vector field $X$. For each $f$ there is an integer $w(f)$ such that $w(Tf(X))=w(X)+w(f)$, so if $X_i,X_j$ are nowhere tangent to $S^1\times\{0\}$, the same must be true for $Y_i,Y_j$, and $w(X_i)-w(X_j)=w(Y_i)-w(Y_j)$.
- Let $\partial_\theta$ be the canonical tangent vector field of $S^1\times\{0\}$, and $\omega$ be a choice of orientation of $S^1\times\mathbb{R}^2$. For any $f$ there is a fixed $c\in C^\infty(S^1\times\{0\})$ such that $\omega(V_1,V_2,V_3)=c\omega(Tf(V_1),Tf(V_2),Tf(V_3))$ for any vector fields $V_i$ on $S^1\times\{0\}$. This along with $Tf(\partial_\theta)=\partial_\theta$ results in several restrictions.

**Post Edit**: In the edited form of the question, the first condition completely rules out the existence of $f$, since $Y_1=\partial_\theta$ is tangent to $S^1\times\{0\}$ while $X_1$ are nowhere tangent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I commented above, I actually know more about the frames and have changed the question accordingly.